# DiscordJS cannot get _roles field after fetching member

Tags: javascript, typescript, discord, discord.js

I am fetching a member as:

```
//...
private user: GuildMember;
//...

try { 
    this.user = await interaction.guild?.members.fetch(SomeUserId)
}catch (e: unknown) {
    return await interaction.editReply("Couldn't find the specific user the in server.")
}
```

`this.user` will contain all the information regarding that specific user. It also includes a field `_roles:['123456789', '123456789']`. How can I get this specific field? Note that doing the following results in '_roles does not exist on type GuildMember':

```js
console.log(this.user._roles)
```

Any way to access this field?

Comment: Per the https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=roles
The fetch method will return a list of GuildMembers which should have the property `roles` rather than `_roles`. Does that give you what you need?

Comment: True. Just saw that too. I'm not entirely sure why it gives the `_roles` as an array outside of the `GuildMember` object so I was slightly confused. Posted the answer that worked for me below.

Answer (score 1):

Found it!

```
...
private user: GuildMember | undefined; // Make sure to add undefined here too. Since .fetch returns a GuildMember or undefined
...

//To get that array use:
Array.from(this.user.roles.cache.keys())

//To get the Collection:
this.user.roles.cache.keys()
```

Leaving this here for that one random person that also has the same issue after 8 years.